# ILMergeで出てしまうエラーの回避

Tags: c#, .net

お世話になります。

.Netにて、生成されたexeと関連するdllを結合して、単体で起動するexeに
変換するILMergeですが、なかなかうまく変換できません。それが、
必ず失敗するのではなく、成功するときもあれば、失敗するときもあるのです。
一度成功したかと思うと、それ以降が失敗してしまいます。

下記が使用しているコマンドです。

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /targetplatform:v4
　/out:"C:\..\A.exe" "C:\...\Z.exe" "C:\...\B.dll"
```

その結果、下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: There were errors reported in B's metadata.
The pdb associated with C:\...B.dll is out of date.
場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

必ず失敗するのならまだしも、たまに成功するのでますます解りません。

原因と対策をお教えいただけないでしょうか。

急務です。

何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: "The pdb associated with C:...B.dll is out of date." ILMergeはpdbファイルの結合も一緒に行いますが、その際 *B.dll 用と思われるpdbファイルが B.dll より古い*、というエラーかと思います。dllだけコピーしてきているからpdbがないとか、何か心当たりはありますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
確かに、pdbファイルは意識していませんでした。
私はVCS2013ExpressDesktopを使用していますが、
一度プロジェクトの参照設定から使用しているdllを削除、
その後もう一度参照に追加すると成功していました。

pdbファイルがないということはないと思いますが、
ご指摘いただいたように、pdbファイルが古いということは
あり得ると思います。

だとすると、その解決方法はどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: pdbファイルはビルド時に生成されますから、dll側とexe側を両方クリーンしたのちにビルドしなおすことで改善する可能性はあります。対症療法ですが。。もしpdbファイルをマージする必要がないのであれば、 `/ndebug` オプションをILMergeに指定するのも一つの手かと思います。

Comment: 再度ご回答、ありがとうございます。
指定のオプションを付けたところ、無事にマージできるようになりました。
本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます。
続いてですが、VisualStudioにてビルドイベントで実行させると
うまくいきませんでした。別スレッドに投稿させていただきますので、
宜しければお知恵をお貸しいただければ幸いです。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

皆様の回答、ありがとうございました。

ILMergeには、Releaseとしてマージする際には、/ndebugオプションを
付けることが解りました。

後、できれば一度プロジェクトをクリーンしてから再ビルドするほうが
良いというのも解りました。

本当にありがとうございました。